# Add an "Insurance" row in Paypal checkout in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

I want to add an extra row in Paypal checkout, the extra row called "Insurance Fee", most preferably, this row is same style as "Subtotal", "Postage and packaging" and "tax".

I tried other method which use an Observer whenever the event of "paypal_prepare_line_items" trigger, the method I used was ->additem.

here is the paypal cart i want.

Descriptions
Amount
Herald Glass VaseHerald Glass Vase
$110.00
Item number:abc
Item price: $110.00
Quantity: 1Item

total$110.00

Tax: $30.80
Postage and packaging: $5.00
Insurance Fee: $4 <<<<<<<< how can i add a row here instead of add an new item?
Total $149.80 USD

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this observer event to add insurance fee

```
<paypal_prepare_line_items>
                <observers>
                    <turnkeye_insurance>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>turnkeye_insurance/observer</class>
                        <method>addScreenToPayPal</method>
                    </turnkeye_insurance>
                </observers>
            </paypal_prepare_line_items>
        </events>
```

observer

```
public function addScreenToPayPal($observer)
{
    $paypal_cart = $observer->getPaypalCart();
    if ($paypal_cart && $paypal_cart->getSalesEntity()) {
        $amount = INSURANCE_FEE;

        if ($amount) {
            $paypal_cart->addItem(Mage::helper('turnkeye_insurance')->__('Insurance'), 1, $amount, 'insurance');
        }
    }

}
}
```

follow this [tutorial](http://astrio.net/blog/magento-development-add-total-row-checkout/)

Comment: hello, i tried his solution, it ends up add a item line on the cart,do you know how to add a row just like "subtotal", "shipping" and "tax" ? thx

Comment: did you check the tutorial link?

Comment: you want to add this on cart page too?

Comment: follow the tutorial it will add in cart also checkout